# does top-level domain name affect user experience?

Tags: user-expectation, psychology

does these new top-level domain names (.guru, .rocks, .ml, .tk) affect user experience? do they like to type generic top-level domain names only?

Comment: great! is should have googled more.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Non .com domain name may have to lower page rank on search engines.**

The disadvantage of having a non .com domain name is that you can't remove extension from the site.

Lets take two cases

CASE 1: Facebook is facebook.com
Person1: Which site do use for social networking.
Person2: Facebook.

CASE 2: Facebook is facebook.co  and facebook.com is not owned by Facebook.
Person1: Which site do use for social networking.
Person2: facebook.co.
[Quora article](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-cons-of-having-a-non-com-domain)

In first case everything is okay. But in second case Person2 must tell that he use facebook.co or if he tells that he uses Facebook then Person1 will think that he uses facebook.com  and on that link Person1 will not find Facebook which will lead to frustration and decrease in traffic.

One of the best part of online business is traffic or popularity and I guess other than .com domain will not have much traffic because users will not like to remember and tell "facebook" instead of "facebook.co" [and yes, that tiny change matters].

A psychological effect should be acknowledged when considering to buy a new domain: Users will be most familiar with .com,.net, .org domains and will associate .com and .net domains with commerce. To which degree this may affect an editor's, poster's, commenter's decision of linking a given domain is a matter of debate at best. But human perception is undoubtedly influenced by a constant weighting of normal vs. abnormal by thresholding a stimulus against a set-point. This way of human perception affects the overall context of any decision making process. If it is worth considering depends on the context, and if your gut feeling is telling you to lean towards a certain domain-extension